# Deploying a Django site using apache2 and mod_wsgi

Tags: virtualhost, mod-wsgi, apache-2.2

I've been trying to teach myself to create and deploy Django apps. I've created a test project and I can browse it using the Django test server. Now I want to deploy it using apache and mod_wsgi.

I followed the installation instructions at the [Quick Installation Guide](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickInstallationGuide) and got mod_wsgi installed. I then went through the example in the [Quick Configuration Guide](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide) and was able to successfully connect to the example output in my browser.

I've now moved on to the Integration With Django (http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/IntegrationWithDjango) section and I can't make any progress with it. Any time I try to browse to the URL I've set up for my project I am instead presented with the output from the example I created with the configuration guide. I've looked at the apache error log and there are no messages in it (I got a few when I was debugging the first example so I know I'm looking at the correct log). I even set 'LogLevel info' to try and get more detail in the logs, but there was none.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Here is my apach2.conf:

```
LockFile ${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}/accept.lock
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 15
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers          5
    MinSpareServers       5
    MaxSpareServers      10
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    StartServers          2
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75 
    ThreadLimit          64
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
<IfModule mpm_event_module>
    StartServers          2
    MaxClients          150
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75 
    ThreadLimit          64
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
AccessFileName .htaccess
<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy all
</Files>
DefaultType text/plain
HostnameLookups Off  [3]: 

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel warn
Include mods-enabled/*.load
Include mods-enabled/*.conf
Include httpd.conf
Include ports.conf
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
Include conf.d/
Include sites-enabled/
```

Here is my httpd.conf:

```
ServerName HomeServer
LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so
```

Here is the VitualHost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ppbase.homeserver
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com

    DocumentRoot /var/projects/ppbase/ppbase
    <Directory /var/projects/ppbase/ppbase>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    LogLevel info

    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/projects/ppbase/django.wsgi
    <Directory /var/projects/ppbase>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And here is the django.wsgi:

```
import os
import sys


projectpath = '/var/projects/ppbase'
projectapppath = '/var/projects/ppbase/ppbase'
if projectpath not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(projectpath)
if projectapppath not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(projectapppath)
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'ppbase.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi

application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Comment: Forget it. I was being a total idiot. I'd set up my vhost file, but I hadn't enabled it in apache.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to enable your vhost file in apache.

Comment: Cheers Bassett :-)